# My Wear app gets rotated and translated up on Moto 360

Tags: android, wear-os, moto-360

i have two problems with my wear application on the Moto 360.

It's working fine on other wear watches.

1. the application rotated 90° left
   (for information i have android:screenOrientation="portrait" in my manifiest, i don't know if it can be related)
2. The application get translated up (my layout is plain blue, there shouldn't be a white area above the chin. It's seems that the app gets translated to compensate for the chin ???

As you can see in this picture:

[image]

I hope you will have ideas to help me solve this problem because it prevents my app from being accepted as a Wear App by google...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: yes i found out that is was caused my setting android:screenOrientation="portrait" in my wear manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out that is was caused my setting android:screenOrientation="portrait" in my wear manifest